# Google app engine: complete revision history

Tags: google-app-engine

I accidentally over wrote a file then proceeded to upload to my app engine site.  Might there be a way to find previous revisions?  I did not set a new version.

Is there a complete revision history of files uploaded or only the current files for the different explicit versions?

Comment: You should really be using source control. Git or SVN will do.

Comment: @IliaFrenkel But why not mercurial.. which is the easiest of all and it's for free on BitBucket?! :)

Comment: @Lipis Lets not make a big deal out of it. Everyone has his/her own preferences. Any source control will help you to avoid such situations.

Comment: Yes I hardly ever update it and just never put it on github.  Windows was supringly useful as it stored a previous revision.  now to make a new repo.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you changed versions, you overwrote files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try look at the admin logs, might find something there
Editors might have some history saved as well
Good luck (Its your chance to write it better)